# CSS div span position text overlaps

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having an issue positioning multiple relative divs, when the text overflows:

[image]

Ideally it should look like:

[image]

With the right '-' vertical allgined center on the div, and enough space for the text to break without overlapping, all of this wihtout using any fixed sizes.

I've managed to isolate the problem on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RASMiranda/xadfxnpn/20/

The critical classes seem to be:

```
#application-subscribe-tab > div {
    position: relative;
    height: 16px;
}
#application-subscribe-tab > div > .application-subscribe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
#application-subscribe-tab > div > .remove-subscribe {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the issue:

```
#application-subscribe-tab > div {
    position: relative;
    ** min-height ** : 16px;
}
#application-subscribe-tab > div > .application-subscribe {
    position: ** relative ** ;
    left: 0px;
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/xadfxnpn/23/

Answer (score 0):

```
#application-subscribe-tab > div {
position: relative;
height: 16px;
padding: 7px 0px;
}
```

```css
body {
    color: #4C4C4C;
    font: 12px/1.4 Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

.col {
    margin-left: 4%;
}
.col {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 291px;
}
.col {
    float: left;
}

.bloc {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 1px #BFBFBF;
    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
div.action {
    padding: 5px 14px 7px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.action {
    min-height: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    max-height: 320px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#application-subscribe-tab {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 325px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#application-subscribe-tab > div {
    position: relative;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 7px 0px;
}
#application-subscribe-tab > div > .application-subscribe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
#application-subscribe-tab > div > .remove-subscribe {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <div id="list-aplication-validated" class="bloc light-green-white">
        <h2>Mes notifications mail validées</h2>
        <div class="action"> 
            <div id="application-subscribe-tab">
               <div>
                   <span class="application-subscribe">OCTOPUS</span>
                   <span class="remove-subscribe" app-tid="262" csa-tid="195">-</span>
                </div>
               <div>
                   <span class="application-subscribe">ARHISTO - ARCHIVAGE HISTORIQUE COMMERCE</span>
                   <span class="remove-subscribe" app-tid="388" csa-tid="195">-</span>
                </div>
               <div>
                   <span class="application-subscribe">GEPETO</span>
                   <span class="remove-subscribe" app-tid="389" csa-tid="195">-</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="application-subscribe">OPOC</span>
                    <span class="remove-subscribe" app-tid="390" csa-tid="195">-</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```